# Apple Photos App Crop-style

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimageview, crop

I want to allow manual photo cropping inside my app but I want to do it as Apple does inside the Photos app (with the nice 3x3 split and finger drag to where the user wants the image to start/end). Does anyone have any tips on how I could implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some open source alternatives that emulate the behaviour, check this out:

- https://github.com/iosdeveloper/ImageCropper
- https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper
- https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController